# Scroll page on text input focus for mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, user-experience

Im making a mobile optimised site with a text input which filters a list as you type. Its similar to this: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html

For phones, it would be a usability benefit if when you selected the input the page scrolled down so the input was at the top of the page. That way as much of the list below would be visible as you type. Is this possible and/or does anyone have experience doing it? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Agreed - that'd be nice for usability.

If you're using jQuery, this should do the trick:

```
$('#id-of-text-input').on('focus', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any option for scrolling on the middle of the page?

Comment: document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset() + (window.innerHeight / 2);  maybe? But you’d want to ensure an on-screen keyboard doesn’t overlap the input (and you have no idea what crazy keyboard person X might use on device Y), so top is probably safer.

Comment: Is this possible to do in Angular too?

Comment: @Siyah Angular is a framework rather than a DOM library, so normally you’d use jQuery for this kind of thing anyway (or just vanilla JS: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#on).

Answer (score 7):

A better solution would be:

```
$('#id-of-text-input').on('focus', function() {
   document.body.scrollTop += this.getBoundingClientRect().top - 10
});
```

Because `offsetTop` (or `.offset().top` if using Jquery) returns the distance from the first positioned *parent*, whereas you need the distance from the top of the `document`.

`getBoundingClientRect().top` returns the distance between the current *viewport* position to the element, u.e. if you're scrolled 300px below the element, it would return `-300`. So adding the distance using `+=` would scroll to the element. `-10` is optional - to allow some space at the top.

Comment: Is this possible to do in Angular too?

Comment: you are missing ); at end

Comment: Added missing `);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('input, textarea').offset().top - 10) }, 1);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Edit your post and use code formatting. Also consider adding any explanation to your code.