# How to scroll / move input field to top of screen with Angular when focused?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have no clue where to start, but I am trying to make a mobile app and I have an input field in the middle of my screen. The problem is that the keyboard, that pops up, is so big, that you hardly can see the input field.

So what I want to do, just like here: [Scroll page on text input focus for mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719848/scroll-page-on-text-input-focus-for-mobile-devices)

Is to **scroll down the input field to the top... when it's focused / tapped on by the user**. And when you click somewhere else, the input field should go back to the place it was.

So how can I do this in Angular? Is this even possible?

**Edit:** I tried it with `CSS`, by `input:focus > body`, but **obviously** this is not possible because the input field is in the body, instead of the other way around. So if there is a CSS fix to *push* all other elements away and focus on the input field (or move it and *blur* the entire screen), I'd be happy too!

Comment: Hmm, I checked that, but it looks like that's just sending me to an ID, while I want to move my actual input field to the top of the screen... so not moving TO it, but moving IT.

Comment: which angular version?

Comment: Just plain old Angular 1, but if I have an example of the both of them, I'd be happy enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple directive would do it:

```
app.directive('focus-scroll', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('focus', function(){
            console.log('focus triggered');
            element.scrollIntoView();
          });
        }
    }
});
```

And using it:

```
<input focus-scroll type="text" ng-model="something"/>
```

Weird.. i just tried the directive and indeed it didn't work. Changing the directive to use snake case did the trick though.

Comment: Could you fiddle this, please, John? I don't understand the code that much to be honest. Especially the "do your scrolling stuff here" comment.

Comment: there is nothing left to fiddle tbh.. the directive binds a function that is executed when the element is focused. the function calls scrollintoView on the element which will result in the browser scrolling the lement into the view. just drop this into your ang1 app and feedback if it doesn't work.

Comment: You sure this works? I tried it, but whatever I do, so even if would click on the input field, it doesn't do a thing...

Comment: see modified answer

Comment: Thanks, but still didn't work... whatever I do, it doesn't move the input field at all. It's just a plain input field where you can add your text. It's not being moved or positioned elsewhere... can you show it in a fiddle?

Comment: well, you now have a simple directive that calls a function when the input field is focussed for ang1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView and hunt around for other similar functions, you are looking for something to scroll that element in the focus function to the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I created something that's maybe helpfull for people that read this. It's actually made in Angular 2+ but should work for js to.

In html:

```
 <input id={{uniqueID}} (focus)="scrollTo(uniqueID)" /> // item.uniqueID if array, can be numbers to if static
```

In the component function `scrollTo(uniqueID)`:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById(uniqueID); // let if use typescript
elmnt.scrollIntoView(); // this will scroll elem to the top
window.scrollTo(0, 0); // this will scroll page to the top
```

This will ensure the input will be shown on top or on top of an **inner element** (div, span however you want to call it).